# 'getDocuments' is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

VScode shows warning using getdocument and other functions from the firebase and Firestore. Can anyone please explain why it is showing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsltJ.png)

Comment: the new version of `firebase` have changed a lot of its syntax, read this [firebase documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#read-data) to know the changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry , just use the function `get()` instead of `getDocuments()`. It basically means that the keyword `get()` is now preferred and supported over the  `getDocuments()`keyword. Just use `get()` and it will work without any problem.